# Passing arguments to a startup executable in Install4j

Tags: java, macos, install4j

I'm creating a OS X installer for our Java app using Install4j. The installer has an application bundle that we want to auto start whenever a user logs in. I need to pass a custom argument to the bundle (we want to tell it to start in minimized mode) but I cannot find any option in Install4j that allows us to do this. Is this achievable and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Add a startup executable on Windows and OS X" action has a "Set the hide flag" property that can be used to launch the application in hidden mode at startup.

Comment: How do I run that at startup?

Comment: "Add startup executable" never worked but since this installer only targets OS X I solved that by running "-e 'tell application "System Events" to make login item at end with properties {path:"/Applications/Degoo/Degoo.app", hidden:true}'" instead and now it works as intended. I'm accepting your answer, since your suggestion to set hidden to true solved the initial issue.

Comment: There is indeed a problem with the  "Add a startup executable on Windows and OS X"  on Mac OS X 10.8 that will be fixed in the upcoming 5.1.7 release.